# Difference between gulp-watch and gulp-nodemon

Tags: node.js, gulp

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/**gulp-nodemon**
- https://github.com/floatdrop/**gulp-watch**

I'm trying to verify if basically they both do the same thing.  Looking at the docs on both it seems so but I could be wrong.  I assume the use case for what you use it for are the same...

right?

If so I'm trying to figure out the advantages / disadvantages of both but I've never used these yet so if you have experience using them, what have you observed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodemon is more configurable. Gulp-watch is for when you just need exactly that, a watcher for files that change based on glob statements.

Nodemon can do the same thing but introduces more advanced features (filters) without the need for additional packages. Furthermore since you can implement lower down in the stack (native node CLI without gulp) it gives you more flexibility should you have to switch between automaters (grunt vs gulp for example).

For your purposes i'd stick with gulp-watch.